# Connecting Blazor Server App to Azure AD - Insufficient Permissions

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to create a new Blazor server app and configure it to use a new Azure Active Directory that I recently created. I have found a couple tutorials online showing how to do this, including one from Microsoft, but I keep encountering an error that says "The user account doesn't have the required permissions to access the domain."

[image: Error Message]

I read online that I needed to verify that my user account is assigned to the Global Administrator role, which I did and it is. I have tried to create 3 different active directories in Azure to see if it was a fluke, but I have received the same error message each time.

Any help that you are able to provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have signed in to Visual Studio with an admin account of the domain (here it should be "thomasagarza@yahoo.com").

[image]

After adding the account, you can apply filter for it (select the domain it is an member in). Make sure you have added it as the guest of that domain and assign Global Admin role to it.

Then all the related domains will be listed when you create a new project with **Work or School Accounts Authentication**. Select the domain which "thomasagarza@yahoo.com" is the admin in and click on **OK**. Generally you won't be required to enter your credential again in this step.

Please note if you have a custom domain for your AAD tenant and have made it primary, the domain listed here will be the custom domain name. In this case, if you manually set the domain as the format "***.onmicrosoft.com", you will get the error you are facing.

Comment: The key was definitely the part about making sure VS had the credentials already.  In my case, it was listed, but it wanted the password re-verified.